# Pass Seller Names to Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

Any idea how to pass list of seller names coming from database to a dropdown menu?

**The get seller from database function:**

```
late String getsellernames = http://ip/sas.php;

  var allSellerNames = [];

  getSas() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(getsellernames));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        allSellerNames = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }

    print('$allSellerNames');
    return allSellerNames;
  }
```

**The edited dropdown**

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    // hint: const Text('Seller'),
                    value: allSellerNames[index][0], //initialnames,
                    items: allSellerNames[index]['seller'].map((ditem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text(
                          ditem,
                        ),
                        value: ditem,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (dValue) {
                      if (dValue != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          initialnames = dValue.toString();
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

This is the edited dropdown button

Answer (score 0):

The error is talking about the onChanged function you declaried and its required is not match. This is becuase you have not declaired the type of the `DropdownMenuItem` and the `DropdownButton` is, then it default takes it as Object type.

There is 2 way to solve the problems:

1. is declaried the type of `DropdownMenuItem` and `DropdownButton` as `DropdownMenuItem<String>` and `DropdownButton<String>` which force the value returned from the button must be String.
2. remove the String from onChanged method to allow Object type value return

   ```
   onChanged: (dValue) {
    if(dValue!=null){
      setState(() {
       initialnames = dValue!.toString();
      });
    }
   },
   ```

Comment: I followed no.2 solution and I got this error: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'. Receiver: "Peter" Tried calling: map(Closure:(dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<Object>)

Comment: can you share your latest DropdownButton code ?

Comment: please how do I do that? I guess it's not from the comment section

Comment: edit the question to add the latest code or you can use github or dartpad to share